# SVG font-size not having effect

Tags: python, svg

I am generating this keyboard SVG using Python's svgwrite library.

The text size and the text placement are not being taken into consideration. The x and y positions relative to the letter group are not respected. The font size which is absolute shows much larger in inkscape.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" width="210mm">
  <defs/>
  <g id="kbgroup" transform="translate(10,10)">
    <g id="Q" transform="translate(0,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-Q" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">Q</text>
    </g>
    <g id="W" transform="translate(19,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-W" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">W</text>
    </g>
    <g id="E" transform="translate(38,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-E" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">E</text>
    </g>
    <g id="R" transform="translate(57,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-R" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">R</text>
    </g>
    <g id="T" transform="translate(76,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-T" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">T</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Y" transform="translate(95,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-Y" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:4px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" x="2.0" y="5.0">Y</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want the text size to be the size expressed in px. The position of insertion of the text relative to the group must be the one expressed in no units and therefore in mm since that is the default unit set using the viewbox.

Comment: A value specified with a `px` unit and one with no unit specified mean the same thing in svg, it's `user units`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units.

Comment: In inkscape, the rectangles are the size I want, i.e., 12.5 x 15 mm and not pixels. The text however is being interpreted as a size in mm and is then multiplied by ~3.5. Also, its position is not correct. It should be 2.5 and 5.0 mm relative to the top left corner of its group. How does one achieve that?
All the sizes I have are in mm because this is supposed to be adapted to a real keyboard which I measured in mm.

Answer (score 0):

It is having an effect just not one that is obvious.  The `height` and `width` value of the SVG node are scaling the drawing overall.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" width="210mm">
```

Watch what happens as you increase and decrease the `font-size` of each letter, and then the height and width of the `svg` node (here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vBMyd/))

While I'm sure what layout you are looking for here is modified version of the SVG you were building (without `mm` as the unit for the size of the `svg` node) and with a slightly larger font that is centered): ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vBMyd/1/))

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="297" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" width="210">
  <defs/>
  <g id="kbgroup" transform="translate(10,10)">
    <g id="Q" transform="translate(0,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-Q" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">Q</text>
    </g>
    <g id="W" transform="translate(19,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-W" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">W</text>
    </g>
    <g id="E" transform="translate(38,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-E" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">E</text>
    </g>
    <g id="R" transform="translate(57,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-R" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">R</text>
    </g>
    <g id="T" transform="translate(76,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-T" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">T</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Y" transform="translate(95,0)">
      <rect fill="black" height="15.0" id="box-Y" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" width="12.5" x="0" y="0"/>
      <text style="text-anchor:end;text-align:start;writing-mode:ltr;     font-size:8px; font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans; fill:white" y="10" x="9">Y</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is actually not what I want. I did not express it clearly, my apologies.

What I want is that the relative position be expressed in mm and the font size in px.